# get the Text of an element with out getting the element into view port

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, viewport

Following is my method where `tableComponent` is the table body element.
This method works fine when the text is visible in a row, but if the row has a scrolling and the text is out of view port, the method fails.

I tried the `CSS` as well, with out luck... 
If I use the `scroltoview` option, I can get the text, but this is kind of a bootstrap, to scroll to the element, I need to find the right row and column, and to find the row and column, I only knows the text that it could appear in that cell.

This is Java, `Selenium webdriver`

```
   public IUIElement getRowContainingText(final String text) {
        return tableComponentElement.findUIElement(By
                .xpath(".//tr[*[self::td|self::th]//text()[contains(.,\""     +   text + "\")]]"));
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide the `html` as well?

Comment: Not possible to share the exact html, but the applicataion is developed using Oracle ADF, and a small frame contains a large table which has some rows and columns out of the view area.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution-

```
List<webElement>rows=tableComponentElement.findElements(By.tagnamr("tr"));
for(webElement element:rows)
{
List<String>tabledata=rows.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
String desiredText=tableData.get(index);
//index will be the postion where text will appear in each row
}
```

Comment: I don't know the index as well, it is a generic method which I need to find a row, which contains the text I am looking for. Columns may reorganized from time to time.. so cannot give a specific column number.

Comment: Just make some modification like-
List<String>tabledata=rows.findElements(By.tagName("td"));for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){if list.get(i).toString().equals(desiredText))